# Javascript - how avoid this multiples functions for same propose?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a set of JavaScript functions and was wondering if I could make a function simpler (e.g. a more global function)?

What I have is a set of 5 toggles for which I would like to write a function `toggleOn` and `toggleOff`. What I wrote so far is :

```
function toggleOn1() {
$('#chk1').bootstrapToggle('on');                       
}

function toggleOff1() {         
$('#chk1').bootstrapToggle('off');  
}

function toggleOn2() {
$('#chk2').bootstrapToggle('on');                       
}

function toggleOff2() {         
$('#chk2').bootstrapToggle('off');  
}

function toggleOn3() {
$('#chk3').bootstrapToggle('on');                       
}

function toggleOff3() {         
$('#chk3').bootstrapToggle('off');  
}

// etc.
```

Comment: `function toggle(what,state) {$(what).bootstrapToggle(state);}`???

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, Or rather `jQuery-event-binding`

Comment: You need to look at your code and start identifying all its 'variables', then you write a single function that accepts those variables. On this case, the element and it's state. Since this is a toggle, you many not even need the 'state' variable. You're clearly learning how to code and it's sad to see so many people down voting your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the Jquery selector to the function

```
function toggle(selector,state){
         $(selector).bootstrapToggle(state); 
}
```

Both the selector and state will be strings.

You can call it like this

```
toggle('#chk1','off');
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
function customToggle(element, state) {
    $(element).bootstrapToggle(state);
}
```

Comment: One note on this answer, you'll need to pass your element in without the jQuery wrapper (so just like customToggle('#chk2', 'off'))

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you have some parameter (part of the function name, something the function's code is doing) that's the same, then turn that "same" into a parameter:

```
function toggleGeneric(id, value) {
   $('#chk' + id).bootStrapToggle(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `selector` as parameter of the `function`

```
function toggleOnOff(selector,state){
         $(selector).bootstrapToggle(state); 
}
```

or you don't need to pass the state if you want to change the state based from previous one:

```
function toggle(selector){
         $(selector).bootstrapToggle(); 
}
```

reference [here](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this..

```
var on = 1;
function toggle() {
if (on == 1) {
 $('#chk1').bootstrapToggle('off');   
 on = 0; }
else if (on == 0) {
 $('#chk1').bootstrapToggle('on');
 on = 1;
 } else { 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to each of your elements and change your code like sew:

```
$('.chk').on('click', function() {
    $(this).bootstrapToggle();
});
```

Toggle should be smart enough to know the difference between on/off.